# The act of calling student names to make list of absent students

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word for the act of calling each student name in a classroom to know which students are present, and which ones are absent?

I used google translate and tried to translate it from other languages which gave me the word *absenteeism* which its English meaning shows that it's not what I'm looking for:

> Absenteeism: the practice of regularly staying away from work or school without good reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the US at least it is called [**roll call**: "the act or an instance of calling off a list of names (as for checking attendance)"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll%20call).

It's also sometimes called [*taking attendance*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20attendance).

Comment: The first phrase that came to my mind was "taking roll". "Taking attendance" is also good. "Roll call" has this meaning, as well as several other shades of meaning.